# uWSGI + Django: How can I get Django's deprecation warnings to be treated as errors?

Tags: django, uwsgi

My goal is to treat Django's deprecation warnings as errors. I've been experimenting with a copy of Django 1.9 and haven't been able to get it work like (I think) it should with uWSGI. This is what I've done:

In my settings.py file, I changed `django.template.context_processors.debug` to `django.core.context_processors.debug` in order to cause `RemovedInDjango110Warning` to be raised. I then ran `runserver` and accessed the site. The warning showed up in the `runserver` output but, as expected, it wasn't treated like an error.

Next, I ran `export PYTHONWARNINGS=error`. After that, I ran `runserver` and accessed the site. This time, the warning was treated like an error, which is what I want.

In an attempt to replicate this behavior with uWSGI, I added this to my uWSGI conf file:

```
env = PYTHONWARNINGS=error
```

I then accessed the site. The warning showed up in the uWSGI log, but it wasn't treated like an error. To confirm that the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable was being set, I added this to my wsgi.py file:

```
print('PYTHONWARNINGS: %s' % os.environ.get('PYTHONWARNINGS', '[not set]'))
```

This caused `PYTHONWARNINGS: error` to be output in the uWSGI log, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not uWSGI configuration solution, but you can add the following snippet to the top of your project's `urls.py`:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)
```